# Failed to load Resource : the server ressponded with the status 404(Not Found) in console in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

This is quiz.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable,  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class QuizService 
{
    readonly rootUrl = 'http://localhost:4200';
    constructor(private http :  HttpClient)
    {
    }
    insertParticipant(name: string, email: string)
    {
        var body = {
            Name : name,
            Email: email
        }
        return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/api/InsertParticipant',body);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Failed to load Resource : the server responded with the status 404(Not Found)   in console in Angular 5

I think its the url issue is there.

My angular version details

- Angular CLI : 1.7.4
- Node : 12.13.0
- OS : win32 * 64
- Angular : 5.2.11

I think the url is having the navigation problem.

How to solve the error?
What is the proper way to route the url in angular 5.2?

Comment: Hi, I've fixed the formatting of your post; you should learn to properly format your question next time. A well written question attracts more answers, and people may not even read a poorly formatted one. Also don't copy & paste the same text at the bottom of your question, it's distracting. You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you don't have backend and try to send a requests into your .ts file (mayby I'm wrong).

But if it's true, you need a server with backend api to make http requests (it can be a server on your local machine or it can be remote server) and you need a method that will process your request.

Request will be look like this `your_server_url/api/insert_participant`.

Also you can you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api to emulate CRUD operations without servers api. It intercepts Angular Http and HttpClient requests that would otherwise go to the remote server and redirects them to an in-memory data store that you control.